# How to find 7 days weather forecast in openweather API?

Tags: api, openweathermap

I am trying to find 7 days weather forecast using openweather API , but when I am calling the openweather API then the data are not coming for the current location, can anyone guide me to find the correct API to get weather forecast for the current location.

API's used so far

```
1. api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name}&appid={API key}
2. https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={API key}
```

Reference links:

1. https://openweathermap.org/forecast5
2. https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api

Request: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=India&appid={MY_API_ID}`
Response: (Added only 2 days data out of 40)

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1600668000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 283.42,
                "feels_like": 282.81,
                "temp_min": 283.42,
                "temp_max": 284.26,
                "pressure": 1018,
                "sea_level": 1018,
                "grnd_level": 862,
                "humidity": 84,
                "temp_kf": -0.84
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 802,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "scattered clouds",
                    "icon": "03d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 32
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 0.1,
                "deg": 22
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0,
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2020-09-21 06:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1600722000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 283.34,
                "feels_like": 282.29,
                "temp_min": 283.34,
                "temp_max": 283.34,
                "pressure": 1016,
                "sea_level": 1016,
                "grnd_level": 861,
                "humidity": 86,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 66
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 0.82,
                "deg": 149
            },
            "visibility": 823,
            "pop": 0.35,
            "rain": {
                "3h": 0.18
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2020-09-21 21:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "city": {
        "id": 3168508,
        "name": "Innichen",
        "coord": {
            "lat": 46.7406,
            "lon": 12.2797
        },
        "country": "IT",
        "population": 3107,
        "timezone": 7200,
        "sunrise": 1600664205,
        "sunset": 1600708262
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the request and the response to the API and any errors you're receiving?

Comment: Have you retrieved an API key yet?  If not, follow the steps to get one here https://openweathermap.org/appid .  If you're just starting out, I would recommend focusing on the one call (https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api) API (since it is free).

Comment: @elderlyman I have collected my API key, but it is not showing the forecast for the current location. Whatever location I am giving the same response comes every time.

Comment: @ZachValenta I have added request and response please check.

Comment: Please note that your request contains `q=India` but your response is coming back with `"country": "IT"` and `"name": "Innichen"`.  For some reason, if you ask for results for India, the server is giving results for a city called Innichen in Italy.  Let's clarify - what city name would you like results for?

Comment: @elderlyman Yes, I am looking for India, but the all-time result comes for Innichen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of issues and it would be helpful if you could narrow them down. But here's my best shot at helping in every way that I can:

For a 7 day forecast, you **need to request a 7 day forecast.**.

In your example for a request `1. api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city name}&appid={API key}` you also included a [link that you used](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5) **which is for a 5 day request.** That's a problem if you want 7 days.

If you want a 5 day forecast, the API you cited in your first example **requires a city name** and (if you want to include a country) it **requires that the country name be in ISO 3166** so India would be "IND" not INDIA.

Whether you want a 5 day or a 7 day, you will need to be more specific than INDIA.

In the case of a 5 day, you will need a city name.  For a 5 day forecast for Mumbai, you can use the API you tried in the first example like this:

```
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=mumbai&appid={yourAPIKey}"
```

In the case of a 7 day, you will need latitude and longitude coordinates.
For a 7 day forecast for Mumbai, you can use the API you tried in your second example like this:

```
   //includes lat and long for mumbai
 "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=19.0760&lon=72.8777&appid={yourAPIkey}"
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

For 7 days forecast you have to pass lat long and api id to below url

"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${api}"

to get the lat long of the searched city, you can create an api call to below url first and then use that data to pass to above url.
[https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${api}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$%7Bcity%7D&appid=$%7Bapi%7D)

Hope this will help you. One way to try this.

// to get the lat long :

```js
const getData = async () => {
    let city = document.getElementById("cityName").value; //input from user.
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${api}`;
    try {
      let res = await fetch(url);
      let data = await res.json();
      let lat = data.coord.lat;
      let lon = data.coord.lon;
      getDatafor7days(lat, lon);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

// passing lat long to get the 7 days forecast :

```js
const getDatafor7days = async (lat, lon) => {
    let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${api}`;
    try {
      let res = await fetch(url);
      let data = await res.json();
      console.log("data", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```